cmake pkg_search_module not finding package even with setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH (linux)
I have an rpm that installs a few shared libraries and includes a .pc file.  The .pc file is installed to /usr/lib/pkgconfig.  Using
pkg-config --libs libNAME --with-path=/usr/lib/pkgconfig

returns the expected results.
The following doesn't seem to make a difference:
set(PKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH TRUE)

setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH with
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/lib/pkgconfig")

pkg_search_modules(MYLIB REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libNAME)

I get the normal package not found fatal error.
Enabling find debug mode
set(CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE TRUE)

also provides zero output on this package.  It just dumps the same error out.  I found this odd, but haven't dug into FindPackage yet to see what's going on.
If I set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH env variable to /usr/lib/pkgconfig, everything is good.
To use CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH with FindPackage, does the search path always have to be part of PKG_CONFIG_PATH?  I was under the impression that using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH alone would tell the macros to search the new path.
CMake version 3.26.5, currently.

The command pkg_search_modules is NOT a find_package or its variant. So variable CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE doesn't affect on that command. Actually, pkg_search_modules is just a wrapper for pkg-config utility, which is executed via execute_process. So you may set variable CMAKE_EXECUTE_PROCESS_COMMAND_ECHO to STDOUT for inspect parameters passed to pkg-config.

Thanks!   FindPkgConfig uses find_library a few places, which responds to CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE.  It's probably not getting far enough in the module to hit those cases.
I added the variable you provided but didn't get much output.  "Package 'myLib', required by 'virtual:world', not found", then a CMake Error at FindPkgConfig.cmake: 607.   It seems that it won't use the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to search even with PKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH set to TRUE.
